# Creating a query to pull unique transaction ID's by date

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I am new to using SQL to create queries in access but had to use it to create a distinct count of transaction id's in a table.  I was able to get that to work however I am having trouble incorporating that into my overall query.

Below is the code - I am basically summarizing a few columns from a table and also adding a column that shows a distinct count of invoice ID's from the same table.  There is one table that is joined to bring in some additional fields.

```
SELECT "Q" & [Quarter] & " " & [Year] AS QUARTER, [0_Time].MONTH, [0_Time].WEEK, Sum(Abracadabra_Sales.Qty) AS SumOfQty, Sum(Abracadabra_Sales.[Total Sell]) AS [SumOfTotal Sell], Sum(Abracadabra_Sales.[Total Sell]-[Total Cost]) AS [GM$], Avg(Abracadabra_Sales.[Total Sell]/[Qty]) AS AUR, Avg(Abracadabra_Sales.[Total Cost]/[Qty]) AS AUC, 

count([Invoice ID]) AS TransCount
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Invoice ID] FROM Abracadabra_Sales)

FROM 0_Time INNER JOIN Abracadabra_Sales ON [0_Time].DAY = Abracadabra_Sales.Date
GROUP BY "Q" & [Quarter] & " " & [Year], [0_Time].MONTH, [0_Time].WEEK;
```

Comment: That's nice.  Do you have a question?

Comment: actually, I think I almost understand your question but could you provide the layout or schema of your tables and the output that you would like to get

Comment: Hi sorry if I wasn't clear, I'll keep the question simple.  I have a query that returns the total count of unique invoice ID's from a sales table.  I cant seem to add other fields from this table to the query - If someone can show me how to add the date field to this query that would get me on my way.

Comment: SELECT count([Invoice ID]) AS TransCount
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Invoice ID] FROM Abracadabra_Sales)  AS [%$##@_Alias];

Comment: FYI - I just realized my original post got cut off, now I understand the confusion!